# Jenkins scripted pipeline to trigger for every new commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is the groovy syntax, that checkout `develop` branch on `Build now`(manual checkout).

```
node('node_1'){
    stage('dev-staging'){

        sh "cd ${WORKSPACE}"

        dir('xyz') {
            git branch: 'develop', 
                credentialsId: '71111-222-333-444-43333333a40',
                url: 'ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc_project/xyz.git'
        }
        dir('def') {
            git branch: 'develop', 
                credentialsId: '71111-222-333-444-43333333a40',
                url: 'ssh://git@10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc_project/def.git'
        }
    }
}
```

---

How to trigger checkout from `develop` branch, on every new commit on `develop` branch? automatic trigger but not manual trigger...

Comment: You can use **Build Triggers** in job configuration to trigger your pipeline.

Comment: @Sers I understand but, I checkout multiple repo. Query edited. So.. do you want me to copy token to multiple repo? Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Webhook to trigger your job in Jenkins on new commit. Repeat same settings in gitlab for both xyz and def repos.

**Jenkins Settings:**

1. Select Build Triggers try webhooks for push events.
2. Select `Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL:
   http://yourjenkins/project/yourproject`, copy job_url.
3. Select push events.
4. Click to Advanced button
5. Find `Allowed branches`, select `Filter branches by name` and enter your branch name.
6. Save

**Gitlab settings:** - repeat same steps for xyz repo also.

1. Got to project integration settings:
   https://10.xx.xx.xx:2222/abc_project/def/settings/integrations.
2. Enter into URL textbox job_url from Jenkins
   `http://yourjenkins/project/yourproject`, select `Push events` and
   press `Add webhook`